# How to make object permissions public when adding them to S3 bucket using boto3 in python

Tags: python, boto3

Managed to make my S3 bucket public but when trying to make the files inside the bucket go public it isn't working.

```
response = s3.Object(bucket_name, "local-filename.jpg").put(Body=open, ACL='public- 
read'("local-filename.jpg", 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s3.upload_file(Filename=, 
               Bucket=, 
               Key=, 
               ExtraArgs={"ACL": "public"})
```

The above code will put the file into s3 as a public when you upload the file to s3.